# Rigify finger control failed to bend after switching the computer from mac to window PC

Tags: add-on, rigify

I made a rig with the older rigify, and there is a finger control which you can scale it up and down to bend the fingers. I animated with the rig in a Mac pro and I have the finger bending in it. However, when I took out project and opened in a windows desktop the fingers are no longer bent. It'd be appreciated if anyone could help. Thanks.

[image]

This is the finger control stuff I talked about.

Comment: oh so that's the reason xD well I feel stupid now. Thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the addons you used on one computer are enabled on the second one.